# How do you run custom functions after Migrate class finishes an import?

Tags: migrations

I have migrate classes to import useres, taxonomy, content, etc.  Some of these are being imported from a CSV source and need to be organized a little better either before or after an import.

How can I run custom functions before and after an import with the [Migrate module](http://www.drupal.org/project/migrate)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what you're asking (running a function prior to or after a single Migration) see the documentation for [Less Commonly Implemented Migration Methods](https://drupal.org/node/1343112). They include:

- **`function preImport()`**
- **`function postImport()`**
- `function preRollback()`
- `function postRollback()`

Note this caveat from the documentation:

> NOTE: If you are running your migrations through the web UI, which
>   chunks the work into batches, if a given migration takes long enough
>   to be broken into separate batches, these functions will be called for
>   each batch. They are called each time the migration is invoked, not
>   just the first (or last, in the complete case).

If you don't like that behavior, then in your `preImport()` or `postImport()` simply use a static variable to see if your custom logic has already run once. [Lullabot Posted a good blog entry on using `drupal_static` back in 2011 on this subject](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7).

With regards to per-record migration completion (like moving 1 song from legacy data store to drupal -- 1 "row" of a migration) take a look at the documentation for [Commonly Implemented Migration Methods](https://drupal.org/node/1132582). They include:

- `function prepareRow($row)`
- `function prepare($entity, stdClass $row)`
- `function complete($entity, stdClass $row)`
- `function createStub()`

Answer (score 0):

I found this especially useful for turning ON and OFF patterns for [Path Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) settings with a simple `variable_set('pathauto_node_MYTYPE_pattern')` when migrating existing aliases into a new site.